# android studio does not install flutter project on emulator(memu)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

i am new to flutter and android at all

first i wanted to run basic flutter program on my emulator(memu) android studio does not found memu so i go to  memu file location and write this command on cmd:

```
adb connect localhost:21503
```

after that i got new error  and this is it:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on G011A in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install B:\Android\jadi\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
Error launching application on G011A.

what should i do plz help...